# HTML elements move when keyboard is opened on tablet

Tags: html, css, keyboard, tablet, smartphone

I made a simple html page for tablet/smartphone (landscape layout).
I have a problem when I tap on a input to write some text, the virtual keyboard move/push every elements.

Screenshot :

[image]

[image]

Any way to prevent that ?

[php and css link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_TfIq6iAYOKfZEh88L8-UsjElhEcMwJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you post your CSS for this element? I believe the issue lies there

Comment: I just uploaded, sorry about a lot of things are not associated with this web page in css.

Comment: Please put the CSS in the question, you're link is obviously broken.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your CSS is tied to a percentage of the view height, so when the keyboard is opened the height becomes smaller and shrinks your container.

if you give your main container a **min-height** you should be able to prevent this happening

Comment: When I debug on tablet, I found this element : `<div id="page-wrapper" class style="min-height: 581px;">`. I never write a min-height for this element. When I open a keyboard, the value of "min-height" is overwrite to 215px and I can't force more...